# Can work on two HTML files

Tags: jquery

How do I work with a JavaScript file in two different HTML pages.
Rather, I want to make a query in jQuery and take a class from the index HTML page and HTML template.

i have a this pages

```
index.html
templeate.html
main.js
```

in pages html i write :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/main.js"></script>
```

but when in my code js i write $('#classtemplate')... finds nothing

Comment: Just include your js file into the html file or in the main file for Eg: index.html

Comment: go to your view:source and try to open the js file, check if it is opening or not . might its not included.

Comment: it isn't opening 
how can i include my file?

Answer (score 0):

Include the script in both files.

For clarification: You put the script in a new file (.js) and refer to that one from both HTML files.

```
<script src="myscripts.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like we add css in diff html pages, we can add a js file also. Make a common js file like custom.js and add it diff pages like:

```
<script src="custom.js"></script>
```